# x must be a label or series

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#this dataset is re-input from csv file as reference  
data = {'account': ['ASSETS', 'LIABILITIES', 'REVENUE', 'COST OF SALES', 'MARKETING','GENERAL EXPENSES','NETT'],
        'JAN': [0, 7014, 39127, 35467, 22487, 3321, 22148.83],
        'FEB': [0, 2581.0, 34234, 19321, 14092, 3304, 2483.36],
       }
#set import as data Frame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#transpose the data Frame for plotting
tb = df.T

#plotting line graph
tb.plot(x='account', y='REVENUE', kind='line')
plt.show()
```

With this dataset, code does not work, here is the dataframe when transposed.[data when transposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TOdQ.jpg)
Here is the error message which i think is the accounts label is not a series.[keyerror accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HSeq.jpg)

But with the same block of code using a different data set, it works!  This one

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
data = {'country': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'gdp_per_capita': [45000, 42000, 52000, 49000, 47000]
       }
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(x='country', y='gdp_per_capita', kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to use practical accounting data for plotting

Comment: Don't put code in images, instead, copy and paste. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tb` you created does not have column names as you are expecting them to be, the columns' names are just numbers - that's why you are getting `KeyError` while trying to get columns `account` and `REVENUE` - there're simply not there from panda's point of view.

I don't know if you can fix it using `.T`, I haven't found any examples in the documentation.

But I can offer an alternative approach to plot what you want. Create a melted dataframe instead:

```
tb = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["account"], value_vars=["JAN", "FEB"]) \
    .rename({"variable": "month"}, axis=1)
```

DataFrame will look like this:

```
             account month     value
0             ASSETS   JAN      0.00
1        LIABILITIES   JAN   7014.00
2            REVENUE   JAN  39127.00
3      COST OF SALES   JAN  35467.00
4          MARKETING   JAN  22487.00
5   GENERAL EXPENSES   JAN   3321.00
6               NETT   JAN  22148.83
7             ASSETS   FEB      0.00
8        LIABILITIES   FEB   2581.00
9            REVENUE   FEB  34234.00
10     COST OF SALES   FEB  19321.00
11         MARKETING   FEB  14092.00
12  GENERAL EXPENSES   FEB   3304.00
13              NETT   FEB   2483.36
```

Then after filtering you can plot the REVENUE per month like this:

```
tb[tb["account"] == "REVENUE"].plot(x='month', y='value', kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer made me think of pandas dataframe in a new rigid way.  Transposing doesn't change the indexing orientation, which was what I was trying to trick the function.  Looks like your meltdown version is the best way to go about it.
From another approach, I can transpose data in the excel sheet before reading them csv in python to do graphs.